# How do I get values from a url in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a url constructed for a Salesforce Site (experience builder). It is currently in the form:
[https://mysite-edition.naxyz.force.com/vs/s/projectname?c__AcctInfo="+AcctInfo__c](https://mysite-edition.naxyz.force.com/vs/s/projectname?c__AcctInfo=%22+AcctInfo__c).
Where acct_info is a fielsd in account and gets passed on url. So i added the following to get the url parameter in my LWC because that key is whats needed to query all the info on the account:

```
connectedCallback() {
    
    const param = "c__AcctInfo";
    const paramValue = this.getUrlParamValue(window.location.href, param);
    console.log("to show my parm :: " + paramValue);
...
}
getUrlParamValue(url, key) {
    return new URL(url).searchParams.get(key);
  }
```

So far so good and works as expected. However now, I have to add some more parameters to the url and these additonal parameters serve only to skip pages that are not needed. In others words, a page would show up based on these paramter values. This where I am stuck and dont know how to grab these values in lwc.

this is what the url would look like:
[https://mysite-edition.naxyz.force.com/vs/s/projectname?c__AcctInfo="+AcctInfo__c+"&ReadyToOrder="+ReadyToOrder__c](https://mysite-edition.naxyz.force.com/vs/s/projectname?c__AcctInfo=%22+AcctInfo__c+%22&ReadyToOrder=%22+ReadyToOrder__c)

ReadyToOrder__c could have a value of "Yes" "No" or nothing. If it yes, then then second page of site would show else it would start from first page same as above previous link. Also, does the ReadyToOrder (key part) have to sart with c__? Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to import the `CurrentPageReference` module from `lightning/navigation`. [Some examples on the LWC developer guide.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url)

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Sample extends LightningElement {

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    currentPageReference;

    connectedCallback() {      
        console.log(`c__myParam = ${this.currentPageReference.state.c__myParam}`); 
    }
}
```

You will want to use `c__` to namespace your parameters, [per Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigate_add_params.htm):

> `state` parameters must be namespaced. For example, a managed package with the namespace `abc` with a parameter `accountId` is represented as `abc__accountId`. The namespace for custom components is `c__`.Parameters without a namespace are reserved for Salesforce use. This namespace restriction is introduced under a critical update in Winter ’19 and enforced in Summer ’19.

Comment: so i wont need the geturlparamvalue function anymore? and would need to create 2 variables c__acctinfo and c__readytoorder where it would be c__readyorder = this.currenPagereference.state.c__readytoorder

Comment: I would recommend using `CurrentPageReference` because that's currently provided within the framework, even if the standard way of referencing the URL in JavaScript works. You can pass multiple query string parameters too.