# How to take fields information from URL and fill out at a LWC form

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I'm getting a URL similar to this: https://abc.sandbox.my.site.com/community/s/abcd?priority=Medium&issue_description__c=Test%20-%20Please%20ignore%C2%A02&request_title__c=Test%20-%20Please%20ignore%201&region__c=AMER%2FLATAM&country__c=Brazil

And I want to fill out an LWC form, how to take this info?

I appreciate every reply!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368375/how-do-i-get-values-from-a-url-in-lwc